# Finding and removing a prefix and returning the amended data

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update

I'm a complete newbie to SQL (using T-SQL at the moment)

I've got a field in a view which contains strings of varying length and format (one of which is SN00000 where '0' could be any old number...)

I want to extract all those that begin with 'SN' and remove this 'SN' prefix, and put that 5-digit string back into the field it came from.

I'm doing this as a step on a job at the moment, with the following code:

```
USE dbo.ABS_AD_CRM
WHERE wWWHomePage LIKE 'SN%' 
SET wWWHomePage = RIGHT(wWWHomePage, LEN(wWWHomePage) - 5)
UPDATE dbo.ABS_AD_CRM
```

To fill you in, the Database has already been selected, andI am specifying to the job to use the specific view `ABS_AD_CRM`. The name of the field I am pulling and pushing to is `wWWHomePage`

Like I said, I am brand new to SQL and have tried lots of combinations and purmutations with this one. Any advice will be taken; I need to feed off of your knowledge, StackOverflow!

Comment: I edited the title... it is considered redundant to put information contained in the tags in the title.

Comment: Cheers Hogan, thanks for sorting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you gave does not look like TSQL or SQL to me.  An update statement in SQL to do as you request looks like this:

```
UPDATE ABS_AD_CRM
SET wWWHomePage = RIGHT(wWWHomePage, LEN(wWWHomePage) - 2)
WHERE LEFT(wWWHomePage,2) = 'SN'
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this code, I ended up writing something similar albiet much more convoluted. This did the job perfectly!